# how to get value from array of objects when key is string with space in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have following data

```
const array = [{"user No": 1, password :1},{"user No": 2, password :2}]
```

how can i get value of user No. i try this

```
const user = array[0].["user No"]
```

but gives me error please help me with solution

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution. i just need to remove dot between array and key

```
const user = array[0]["user No"]
```